A version of determinacy for all sets
Under ZF + AD, some games are undetermined because of lack of choice.  In fact, the axiom of choice is equivalent to determinacy of games of length 2.  However, we can ask whether the lack of choice might be the only exception to determinacy, and we formalize this as follows.
Assume ZF + DC.
Definition: A weak quasistrategy is like a strategy, except that before making a move, the player can give the referee a nonempty set, and receive some element of the set, which may affect the player's actions.  (For example, if your opponent played a countable ordinal, you can use this to get a real encoding it.)  A weak quasistrategy is winning iff all plays consistent with it are winning for the player.
Note: For comparison, a quasistrategy requires that the set given is a set of moves, and that the player plays the element chosen by the referee.  Also, all games here are perfect information two-player games with alternating moves, and exactly one player winning each play; games and strategies are set-sized rather than proper classes.
Axiom of universal weak quasideterminacy:  Every game of length $ω$ is weakly quasidetermined, that is one of the players has a winning weak quasistrategy.
Questions:
 - Has the axiom or a similar statement ever appeared in literature before (besides being briefly mentioned in my work)?
 - Is the axiom consistent, or at least not known to be inconsistent?  Also, what is the strength of its restriction to moves being sets of reals?
 - What are some of its interesting consequences?  Does it imply $\text{AD}_ℝ$?
Using DC, at most one player can have a winning weak quasistrategy.  Furthemore, using DC, weak quasideterminacy implies the axiom of determinacy (AD).  Other consequences are below.
Games of countable length: The axiom of universal weak quasideterminacy implies its extension to games of arbitrary countable length.  Proof: For a countable ordinal $λ=α_1+α_2+...$, we can convert a length $λ$ game $G$ to length $ω$ $G'$ by requiring on round $i$ for player 1 to play a weak quasistrategy (or its set of possible outcomes) for the next $α_i$ moves of $G$, and player 2 to respond with an outcome.  In terms of existence of winning weak quasistrategies, $G$ and $G'$ are equivalent.  For player 1 weak quasistrategies, this holds in ZF + DC.  For player 2, to convert a winning $G'$ weak quasistrategy $S$, at round $i$, using weak quasideterminacy for length $α_i$, ask for (and follow) a weak quasistrategy for the next $α_i$ moves for which all outcomes are consistent with $S$.
Note: For games of length $ω_1$ and higher, the problem is that no sequence might be consistent with a weak quasistrategy.  Thus, the impact of our axiom on the uncountable might be limited.
Supercompactness of $ω_1$: The axiom implies that $ω_1$ is supercompact (in terms of ultrafilters), i.e. for every uncountable set $X$, there is a normal fine countably complete ultrafilter on $P_{ω_1}(X)$.  Proof: Put the $S⊆P_{ω_1}(X)$ into the ultrafilter iff player 1 has a winning weak quasistrategy in the game where the players repeatedly choose countable subsets of $X$, and player 1 wins iff their union is in $S$.  Winning weak quasistrategies for payoffs $S$ and $T$ can be combined to get a winning weak quasistategy for $S∩T$, and similarly for countable intersections.  For diagonal intersections, at each move, the player can ask for weak-quasistrategies corresponding to elements already played (one per element), and follow all of them by pretending that some of the elements were added by the other player.
Notes:
- The strength of supercompactness of $ω_1$ might only be around a Woodin limit of Woodin cardinals (On supercompactness of $ω_1$ by Ikegami and Trang), but weak quasideterminacy plausibly reaches the consistency strength of ZFC + supercompact, if not higher.
- $\text{AD}^+$ + supercompactness of $ω_1$ proves $\text{AD}_ℝ$.
- I suspect that universal weak quasideterminacy proves that $Θ=Θ_α$ for some limit $α$.
- Weak quasideterminacy where the moves are sets of reals gives $P(ℝ)$ supercompactness of $ω_1$ and thus has consistency strength above that of $\text{AD}_ℝ+\text{DC}$ (Determinacy from strong compactness of $ω_1$ by Trang and Wilson).
- For moves restricted to reals, we get $ℝ$ supercompactness of $ω_1$. ZF + DC + AD + "$ℝ$ supercompactness of $ω_1$" is equiconsistent with ZFC + $ω^2$ Woodin cardinals (Structure theory of L(R, µ) and its applications by Trang).
A connection with forcing: The axiom of universal weak quasideterminacy holds iff every length $ω$ game in $V$ is determined in some $\operatorname{Col}(ω_1,X)$ for an uncountable $X$.  Proof:  In one direction, the collapse allows one to uniformize the strategy, and by countable closure, no new plays are added.  In the other direction, a winning weak quasistrategy is encoded by a name for a generic winning strategy; at each step, the referee will pick a forcing condition that settles the move by the player (and by countable closure of the forcing, the player wins a resulting game).
ZFC models: If we can add a well-ordering of $V$ with every set added by homogeneous countably-closed forcing (a proper class of Löwenheim-Skolem cardinals should suffice), we get a model of ZFC with determinacy for countable length games on ordinals with $\mathrm{OD}$ payoff.  The consistency of that is open:  One of its consequences is that for every regular uncountable cardinal, its $ω$-club filter is an HOD ultrafilter, and thus every regular uncountable cardinal is $ω$-strongly measurable in HOD, and the consistency of that is open.

What you call a quasistrategy is also called a policy. So you play in accordance with a policy.

If you change the axiom to assert that exactly one player has a winning quasi-strategy, then over ZF this implies DC, and in ZF+DC it is equivalent to your axiom. So this way of proceeding avoids the need to assume DC.

Can you clarify the role of the referee in the weak quasi-strategy case. I'm unsure what it means to have a play in conformance for the weak case as opposed to the quasi-strategy case. For example, what if there can be no referee making those choices? Then there are no plays in conformance, so the quasi-strategy is vacuously winning?

Oh, I see, in the weak case the referee is making choices, but there is no assumption of referee choice function, but rather only valid plays, which will be OK by DC. The referee choices only be made during the course of the plays, considered separately.

@JoelDavidHamkins Correct.  An equivalent formulation is that player 1 has a winning weak quasistrategy for $G$ iff player 1 has a winning strategy in the game where before making a $G$ move, player 1 sends a nonempty set to player 2, and player 2 must reply with an element.
